# How to size QMainWindow to fit a QTableWidget that has setVerticalHeaderLabels

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget, sizehint

Here is the sample code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, \
    QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
import sys

DATA = {
    f'col{i}': [f'{i * j}' for j in range(1, 10)] for i in range(1, 10)
}


class Table(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, d):
        m = len(d[next(iter(d))])
        n = len(DATA)
        super().__init__(m, n)

        hor_headers = []
        for n, (key, values) in enumerate(DATA.items()):
            hor_headers.append(key)
            for m, item in enumerate(values):
                qtitem = QTableWidgetItem(item)
                self.setItem(m, n, qtitem)
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(hor_headers)
        # the sizeHint works fine if I disable this line
        self.setVerticalHeaderLabels(f'row{i}' for i in range(1, m + 2))

        self.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.resizeRowsToContents()

    # improves the situation but still the window is smaller than the table
    def sizeHint(self):
        hh = self.horizontalHeader()
        vh = self.verticalHeader()
        fw = self.frameWidth() * 2
        return QSize(
            hh.length() + vh.width() + fw,
            vh.length() + hh.height() + fw)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('<TITLE>')
        table = Table(DATA)
        self.setCentralWidget(table)
        # did not work
        # self.setFixedSize(self.layout().sizeHint())


def main(args):
    app = QApplication(args)
    main_win = MainWindow()
    main_win.show()
    raise SystemExit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Here is the result:

[image: with setVerticalHeaderLabels]

The 9th row and the 9th column are not shown and there are scroll bars.

If I comment out the `self.setVerticalHeaderLabels(f'row{i}' for i in range(1, m + 2))` line then it will work:

[image: without setVerticalHeaderLabels]

How can I perfectly fit the main window to the table widget while having vertical header labels?

As you can see in code comments, I have tried the solutions suggested at [python qt : automatically resizing main window to fit content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34637099/python-qt-automatically-resizing-main-window-to-fit-content) but they are not are not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when a complex widget like an item view is not yet "mapped", the *actual* size of its children (headers and scroll bars) is not yet updated. Only when the view is finally shown and possibly added to a layout, then it will resize itself again in order to properly resize its children using [`updateGeometries`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#updateGeometries).

This means that, until that point, the size of each header is based on its default basic contents (the row number for a vertical header).

The solution is simple: don't use the header size, but their hints, which are computed using the actual text that is going to be displayed:

```
def sizeHint(self):
    hh = self.horizontalHeader()
    vh = self.verticalHeader()
    fw = self.frameWidth() * 2
    return QSize(
        hh.length() + vh.sizeHint().width() + fw,
        vh.length() + hh.sizeHint().height() + fw)
```